# iOS UITableView Scroll to bottom of section

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am going to make a tableview with 2 sections inside it. I can add cells to every section programmatically and when i add, i scroll to the end of tableview using

```
[_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

My question is how can i scroll to the end of the section 0, so that when user add a cell to section 0, tableview scroll dynamically to the last cell in section 0.

thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try with this code:

```
int yourSection = 2;
int lastRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:yourSection] - 1;
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath lastRow inSection:yourSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

You get the numbers of rows in your section, then scroll to that indexPath.

Comment: This will give you an index out of bounds on that row number. You need to subtract 1

Comment: Always remember to check if that section exist and have more than that rows count, or it will crash..

Answer (score 15):

All the suggestions above are correct, at least based on the docs.  But it did not work in my case - I could not get the scroll to show the last row in the table view.  I had to add a delay in scrolling to make that work.

```
- (void)scrollToTheBottom:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowCount-1 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:animated];
}
```

I called the above as:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self scrollToTheBottom:YES];
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a lot of computing in one of my section and no scrolling solution would work except for this one.

Comment: Thank you. This solutions fixes the problem of the last cell not being visible when you scroll to the last cell.

Comment: Thnks a Lot for this, I try a Lot but can't work any code but your code is working for me thnks again..

Answer (score 4):

when you inserting row at end you have its index path, you can use scrollToIndexPath method of tableview to scroll

```
[self.liveChannelsTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:IndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, this is solution in Swift:

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {
        let sections = self.numberOfSections
        let rows = self.numberOfRowsInSection(sections - 1)
        self.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: rows - 1, inSection: sections - 1), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just have a small addition. Last line of the function should be:
`self.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: rows - 1, inSection: sections - 1), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: animated)`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 it's been updated to:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1), section: 0)
self.commentsTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
```