# Animate scrolling to bottom of tableview on button tap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the below code to scroll to the bottom of my table view when my "send" button is tapped. That said, the animation seems "choppy" even though I've set animated to YES. **E.g.** When the button is tapped, my entire table view content clears (goes white), and then reappears at the bottom of my tableview (vs. the smooth scrolling animation I'm looking for?)

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)sendReply:(id)sender {

    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX) animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160484/ios-uitableview-scroll-to-bottom-of-section you can find you answer in the above link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS UITableView Scroll to bottom of section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160484/ios-uitableview-scroll-to-bottom-of-section)

Answer (score 2):

Call this `scrollTableToBottom` method in your button action

the condition is used to check any row is there or not. you may ignore that and handle accordingly

```
- (void)scrollTableToBottom {
    NSInteger rowNumber = [self. tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    if (rowNumber > 0) {
        [self. tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
    }
}
```

let me know if you have any question.

Happy coding.

Comment: Still no smooth animation :/

Comment: make animated:YES and see, I have written it NO in code

Comment: Strangely enough, now it just stopped scrolling all together.

Comment: @Brittany, is there any key board displaying when you clicked the send button?

Comment: Tried it with keyboard visible and without it visible - no animation either way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use default animation of tableview itself

```
    int lastRowNumber = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
    if (ip  > 0) {

    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

find your Last indexPath and Try this

```
 [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:true];
```

hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

```html
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (messagesTableView.contentSize.height > messagesTableView.frame.size.height) 
    {
        CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, messagesTableView.contentSize.height -     messagesTableView.frame.size.height);
        [self.messagesTableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    }
}
```

check this and let me know

Comment: Still no animated movement :/